# Having @ModelAttribute in links when using Spring HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I'm building urls to my controller methods using tools that Spring HATEOAS provides. The problem I see now is that, I can't generate the link with necessary request parameters when I use @ModelAttribute to aggregate these parameters. 
I use @ModelAttribute like this not to work with a lot of request parameters in my service:

```
@GetMapping("/entities")
    public Resource<Entity> get(@ModelAttribute Criteria criteria) {
}
```

When I try to build a link to the method, it does not include accountId that I have in model attribute. I expect it to have as a request parameter.

```
linkTo(methodOn(MyController.class).get(new Criteria(accountId)))
```

Is there a way to add @ModelAttribute fields as request parameters? Usually they are sent as request parameters, thus I expected Spring to do it automatically.